# geometry on a torus ( or other regular non-constant Gaussian curvature planes)

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

Can somebody point me to a publication on geometry on a torus (or an other regular  non-constant Gaussian curvature plane, i just think a torus is the simplest form of it)

I want to learn more about the theorems of free rigid movement (which are invalid on a torus, isometric triangles have different area's depending on where on the torus they are)

I am interested in the geometrical and philosophical concequences of it.

Comment: You are looking for something more specific than an overview of Riemannian geometry?

Comment: (Note too that a torus does not necessarily have non-constant Gaussian curvature!)

Comment: @user7530 thanks for your reply

Basic Riemannian geometry would be good as well ( something like "Riemannian geometry for philosophers) I would like a publication that limits itself mostly to 2 dimensional planes,  goes further than just constant curvature planes , and quite a lot of drawings  not sure what to make of your second comment, you mean that in one direction the curvature (along the toroidal direction ) or do you mean something else

Comment: Maybe you'll find this interesting? https://archive.org/details/PhilosophyOfGeometryFromRiemannToPoincare

Comment: David Hilbert; Cohn-Vossen. Geometry and Imagination.

Comment: @user7530 thanks for the link i not much diagrams but an interesting read anyway, but i want to see the problem with my own eyes not read what other write about it :)

Comment: @GilBor thanks for the  link but it is more an art book than a math book (only saw a little bit of it)